# How should I deal with latency in game development?

Tags: python, pygame, latency

I'm working on a hobby project consisting of a multi-player web browser game.
It is my first and I have just stumbled into the latency issue.

**I am trying to make user control as smooth as possible and latency is getting in the way.**

I reckon that average latencies might be around 80-200ms and that for virtually-smooth control a command-action delay needs to be less than 100ms.

I have a few questions:

- **Would it be good practice to try and send user actions 100ms before required**? e.g. User keeps the '->' arrow key pressed, I submit the right arrow key action 100ms before action needs to be submitted to a server.
- **How do developees keep consistency/synchonise between what is happening on the online server and on the client?**
- **Any tips or recommendations?**

---

Thanks guys, help would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: try asking at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1) Yes, but if you're doing real time movement like that, I would consider rendering it locally (using collision detection and what not) and then validation on the server to ensure they didn't cheat it (i.e. update the position on the server every second, and make sure they could have gone from A to B in one second, etc.)

Question 2) Every so often (quarter, half, full second) you send a packet with environment updates of what other players did and what npcs did and the like.

Question 3) Develop then profile. Make it the way you want it to logically. Then, if you find the playability is too laggy, work on optimizing the interface and networking layer. You might find it to be just fine!

Comment: thank for this! I was expecting people to complain about the question being too generic, even though I do not really know how to avoid it. Your answers are very useful, Thanks! Is there any useful resource you could point me to by chance?

Comment: @RadiantHex no problem. The first two questions weren't very general at all, and the last one was simply an invitation to personal commentary, which is the best part of SO. As for resources, all I can say is just ask questions as they come up (obviously, Google first!!) As a side note, I find the answers on gamedev are a lot more closed minded and opinionated than those on SO. My advice is that if you have a question that would be asked the same if it were another application, but happens to be a game, translate it to out-of-game context, tag it with game-dev, and ask it. {continued...}

Comment: This lets you draw upon the expertise of everyone, whether it's order-entry systems or telecoms, but the guys who do games for a living/in their spare time will still be able to offer that pointed, specific insight. If you had asked this about an ajax order-entry system, I would have told you the same answer for all three questions. Render, then validate. Update workspace state at regular intervals. Develop, then profile. On gamedev, you'd get "omg don't use python for games" or something.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing is to load resources when needed. That is, in most 3D 'moving'-games, load resources as approaching the objects needing them.